# Numerical PDE: How can I incorporate boundary conditions for the Laplace-Beltrami eigenvalue problem on a manifold?

Tags: partial-differential-equations, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, numerical-methods, laplacian, manifolds-with-boundary

**Problem description**: I have a 2D smooth manifold with boundary $M$ embedded in $\mathbb R^3$, discretized by a triangular mesh $T$, and need to find the eigenfunctions of the Laplace-Beltrami operator $\Delta$ on $M$ (the Riemannian metric of $M$ is induced from its $\mathbb R^3$ embedding). Since $M$ is a manifold with boundary, I need the solution to be:
$$
\Delta f=\lambda f\ \ \textrm{in}\ \ M,\qquad f=0\ \ \textrm{on}\ \ \partial M.
$$

**Numerical formulation**: For a numerical solution, I apply the finite element method to the triangular mesh $T$. Let $V$ be the vector denoting the values of $f$ at the vertices of $T$. Then $\Delta$ can be discretized by the cotan-Laplacian matrix $L$ (see e.g. [here](https://graphics.stanford.edu/courses/cs468-13-spring/assets/lecture12-lu.pdf)), and a mass matrix $M$ (a diagonal matrix denoting the area of each vertex), i.e. $\Delta \approx M^{-1}L$. The eigenvalue problem (not considering boundary conditions) is then:
$$
M^{-1}LV=\lambda V\iff LV=\lambda MV.$$
Since $L$ and $M$ are both symmetric and positive semi-definite, this amounts to a [generalized eigenvalue problem](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1903.11240.pdf), which can be solved with existing numerical linear algebra algorithm/packages.

**My question**: Is there a (standard?) numerical formulation of the eigenvalue problem that incorporates the desired boundary conditions, which can be solved with existing linear algebra packages? Naively the boundary condition leads to an additional constraint:
$$
BV=0
$$
where $B$ is a diagonal matrix, with the $i$-th diag element is $1$ if $V_i$ is a boundary vertex and $0$ otherwise. However, there doesn't seem to be an algorithm that allows incorporating such additional constraints.

More generally, is it possible to use other boundary conditions, e.g., Dirichlet, Neumann, or these two mixed?

Comment: I suggest to read: https://doc.freefem.org/models/eigen-value-problems.html, the main point is to implement Dirichlet Bc  using "exact penalization".